# Finding the port number used in client

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

Is there any way to programatically find the port that was assigned to the client when the client calls a connect() function.

getsockname is implemented in the server. But what should be used in client ?

Answer (score 3):

`connect()` implicitly calls `bind()` to assign a name to the socket if you didn't do it yourself. Once the `connect()` call succeeded, you can use `getsockname()` on the socket to retrieve the port.

It is also useful when you let the OS choose the port for you when calling `bind()` (with a port number equal to 0) and you want to know which port was assigned to the socket.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the port number used by the peer by using `getpeername()`, as in the following code fragment, for IPv4:

```
    int s = ... // socket number
    struct sockaddr_in sa;
    socklen_t len = sizeof sa;
    if (getpeername(s, (struct sockaddr *)&sa, &len) < 0)
        perror("getpeername()");
    else
        printf("port %d\n", ntohs(sa.sin_port));
```

Also, on the server side, where you call `accept()`, `accept()` itself will return a filled `sa` which gives the peer's port.

IPv6 is similar: see for example http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/getpeernameman.html.